# Flash Builder 4.7: How to force the compiler output the resulting swf in particular folder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

We're developing a game and the project is well separated and structured. There are projects for different kind of things, such as UI, main-logic, gameplay, etc. Just how it's supposed to be.

Now, the main app project (that runs with Flash Player), uses a folder that is called assets.
I want one of the other projects (the Logic project) to be able to output in "assets/logic". 
To do so I first tried (in the Logic project) with including the parameter -output in the compiler settings, but FB rejected it.

Then I tried to set the Output folder from ActionScript Library Build Path menu. I managed to set it to that folder, but it just outputs a SWC file, called just like the project is, and I just cannot force it to generate a swf file with a name I specify. That sucks.

Furthermore, I'd like to force the Logic project to compile itself and generate into that folder **before** the main project does, so that it includes that latest from the Logic project.
So how do I achieve these things?